# Codeigniter custom route works but controller outputs wrong route on running code after page load

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes

I have this route setup,

$route['admin/company'] = "company";

This works nicely if you go to it, on this page I have 2 forms for adding and removing companies from a database, when this code is run in the controller and outputed back to the browser the url will change to the direct route to the controller so;

1st load page = /admin/company

submit form = /company/

Is there a special way to avoid this?

I should point out this only happens on load view not the redirect.

I am outputting the view like so from the controller:

```
//check which form is being submitted.
if ($this->input->post('form2')){
    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Field validation failed.
        //Create a variable with errors assigned to form 2
        $data['form2_errors'] = validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('admin/header', $data);   
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_navigation', $data); 
        $this->load->view('admin/company_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');  
    } else {
        //query the database
        log_message('debug', 'company add() called from controller');
        $this->result = $this->company_model->add($name);

        //basically if there is somthing in the result varible IE the query to add worked then .... 
        if($result) {
            redirect('admin/company_view', 'refresh');
        } else {
            //tell user problem with query
            $data['form2_errors'] = "Error: 0001";
            $this->load->view('admin/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_navigation', $data); 
            $this->load->view('admin/company_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('admin/footer');  
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I started using codigniter yesterday so please correct me on anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is a htaccess rewrite all I can do for this? this would be awfully messy to implement surely someone can help?

Comment: Can you post your form code? I suspect you are submitting directly to the controller and not the controller's route.

Comment: Yeah, check your form's action URL.

Answer (score 0):

As Cryptic & Cryode said in the comments above it was my form submit url.

instead of:

```
    <?php echo form_open('company'); ?>
```

I should of used:

```
    <?php echo form_open('/admin/company'); ?>
```

Many thanks guys!